# Does LXC support IPSET6+?

Tags: ip, lxc, proxmox, debian-jessie

I would like to use a new firewall-extension for PLESK on a Proxmox-LXC.

Now the support of the firewall-extension wrote me this message:

> Does LXC support ipset 6+? If not then I wouldn't recommend using our
>   product within a VPS.

Good question. Does it? Do you have any experiences with that?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. What does LXC have to do with ipset? What is this firewall-extension?

Comment: I was wondering, too. But I thought there is something I dont see. This is the extension: https://www.danami.com/products/plesk-addons/juggernaut-security-and-firewall

Answer (score 0):

Debian jessie includes [ipset 6.23](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/ipset), so that should be no problem. But because your VPS provider uses LXC, you will need to ask them to enable ipset to work in your container.